# redraw dialog operator with check() doesn't work

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to redraw the dialog operator while is it open, but the `check()` function didn't work.
Am I using it wrong ?

```
   import bpy
   
   class Test(bpy.types.Operator):
       bl_idname = 't.test'
       bl_label = 'MyTest'
       bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
       
       text : bpy.props.StringProperty(options= {'TEXTEDIT_UPDATE'})
       
       def execute(self, context):
           return {'FINISHED'}
       
       def draw(self, context):
           print('draw')
           layout = self.layout
           layout.prop(self, 'text')
           layout.label(text= self.text)
           
       def invoke(self, context, event):
           self.text = ''
           return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=1000)
       
       def check(self, context):
           print('check')
           return True
```

The  check function get called every time I add/remove a letter from the text string, but the dialog isn't redrawn, like the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=check#bpy.types.Operator) says.

So 1 solution is to simulate the key 'Enter' and a 'left click', but I don't know how to do this either within an add-on.